# How do I call images from '/media/' using relative URLs in Django?

Tags: python, django, image, django-templates, media

I want to call logo.png and favicon.ico that are stored in the `media/tmp` folder using `{% media 'tmp/logo.png' %}`

With my current configurations, I can call `.css` and `.js` files from the `static` folder with no problem, but I don't understand what goes wrong when calling from `media`.

I have the following configurations in `settings.py`:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

And this is my folder configuration:

```
myproject
   ├── myproject
   ├── blog (app)
   ├── media
   │    └── tmp
   │         ├── logo.png
   │         └── favicon.ico
   ├── static
   ├── static_in_env
   └── templates
```

This is the error message I get:

```py
Invalid block tag on line 21: 'media'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

When I try:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% media tmp/favicon.ico %}">
```

and

```html
<img src="{% media tmp/logo.png %}" class="custom-logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```html
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get a warning because favicon.ico is not found

Comment: Can i see the folder/file structure in your app?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was organizing this wrong.

`/media/` is not for images that are part of the templates. That's what `static` is for. So I dropped the logo and favicon in an `img` folder inside `static` and I called them using `{% static ... %}`.